# Set the value of a struct field with reflection when the field is a pointer-to-x

Tags: pointers, go, reflection, struct

I have a struct of pointers to various primitives. The struct is a config for an application and the reason the fields are pointers is so I can determine between a field set to the default and a field that hasn't been set at all - to enforce "required" fields.

Here is a simple example:

```
type Config struct {
    A *string
    B *int
    C *bool
    D *[]string // wildcard!
}
```

So I grab the `reflect.Value` via `reflect.ValueOf(*cfg)` which gives me a `.Field` on each element, which I iterate through.

The thing is, each element doesn't pass `CanAddr` or `CanSet`, I can't seem to find a way to set the value held behind the pointer. Is this a limitation of the language? Will I need to make my fields non-pointers? That would suck as there would be no way to determine if a user specified an empty string or just didn't set it at all for example.

*Oh and bonus points for setting/appending a []string field! That one confused me even **without** pointers thrown in the mix!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace these lines:

```
t := reflect.TypeOf(*cfg)
v := reflect.ValueOf(*cfg)
```

with

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(cfg).Elem()
t := v.Type()
```

to get an addressable value.

The value created by `reflect.ValueOf(*cfg)` has no reference to addressable memory. The fix is to dereference the pointer in the reflect domain.

Regarding the []string. Because there's a difference between a null slice and an empty slice, there may be no need to use *[]string.  In any case, use the reflect.Append function to append to a slice:

```
var s []string
v := reflect.ValueOf(&s).Elem()
v.Set(reflect.Append(v, reflect.ValueOf("hello")))
v.Set(reflect.Append(v, reflect.ValueOf("world")))
fmt.Println(s) // prints [hello world]
```